# cache .ajax results and use them when back to page(back to results)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, caching

I have an asp.net page where i do some search on the database to fill employees table

My table structure

```
Id    Full Name           Position   Degree                             

1     Carl Iken(href)     Manager    Doctorate

......
```

To do that I use .ajax and call a webservice

To view the details of an employee, I click the href full name. The problem is that when I click back to results, the table reloads again, that means call to database again and the user waiting. How can I avoid that, caching in jquery? A trick? Webservice caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache that at a number of different levels. If your page isn't reloading you can use the [jquery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) apis or in your web service you can cache it, using the [wcf caching support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443.aspx). If you're using html5 you could look at [session storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute), the list of options is huge, it really depends on your needs. If you're a low traffic site you may not need to cache it, a lookup like you've described shouldn't have a huge overhead, if it's being slow you may need to check if you're missing indexes on the backing database.

If you have a high traffic site and your database is very large then perhaps you should cache at every level possible. It's hard to answer this in a concrete fashion without more information on your setup/usage numbers.